# trying to change permissions on files in a directory to read only

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a directory which currently hase the following permissions drwxrwsrwx 
I need to restrict permissions on the files under the directory to read only but when I use chmod 644  I get permission denied on the directory, what chmod command should I use?

Thanks
Nic

Answer (score 3):

Directories need to be executable, so use `chmod 755`. Since you didn't have the executable bit set, you were not allowed to visit the directory, hence the "permission denied" error.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I've just tried chmod 755 and I'm still able to open, edit and save files under the directory??

Comment: Do you own the files under the directory? If so, then of course `755` will allow you to read and write them. If you don't want to be able to write them, set it to `555`.

Comment: Good point! I'm testing using my own directory, will create one using a different user. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may also choose to set permissions in multiple steps to ensure the right files/directories are given appropriate permissions. As Nicola indicated directories must be executable and readable (chmod a+rx) but the files may be read only (chmod o-wx).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have permissions on that dir:

```
sudo chmod 755 <dir>
```

followed with a password